# Static files not loading in django 1.6

Tags: css, django

My structure looks something like this:

```
myproject/
         app1/
             static/
                   css/
                      style.css                 
         myproject/
                  settings.py
         static/
               css/
                  style.css
         db.sqlite3
```

in settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..'))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # blank
)

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}
```

in my index.html I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css" />
```

I am trying to load css from myproject/static folder but whenever I load index.html it's looking into /app1/static/css/style.css, db.sqlite3 is working though.

I even tried removing app/static folder, it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. add `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of your template
2. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" />`

In `settings.py`,

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

No need of `STATIC_ROOT`, if you're running on localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the Static tags to load your files in the templates:

At the beginning of your html file you have to put

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

then add the static tag in your path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %} />
```

see the documentation in django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

kudo to the one who just answered you got it faster ;)

Comment: It should be `{% static "css/style.css" %}` instead of `{% static "/css/style.css" %}`